# Excel sheets In Selenium WebDriver

Tags: excel

I have to read data from excel sheets to forms I automate using Webdriver2 and Testng but most of the time i am faced with the problem that the entered data in excel is not correctly put into forms while running the script.for e.g- 
if I enter 2015 in excel( for an year field) it puts 1900 in form ,If I change the format of cell to text in excel, it works fine but then some other field is incorrectly entered.Like I had a scenario where the date field in form had format dd.mm.yyyy  and the time had format hh:mm. So, it was entering correct values from excel( even though my excel lib code had format like dd/mm/yyyy) but for time field if i enter 31:12(any value greater than 24) it puts something else in form like 52:0.

I want to know, is there a way to format excel in such a way that it puts whatever data i put in cell regardless of format change. 
I have tried changing the format , using regular expressions( works fine) and implemented suggestions from Web but sometimes nothing works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure this has nothing to do with Selenium,The problem is with reading data from excel. [ask]

Comment: I removed the Selenium tag since this question has nothing to do with it. I would suggest that you add a language tag, e.g. Java, C#, etc.